# Validating data the is in another domain

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm writing a system that has a user with karma points.
Here the relevant key points of the system :

- Each user can make a post, and any interaction with a post on the system is awarding the user some karma.
- If someone downvoted your post, you will lose karma.
- With the karma the user earned he can buy badges and display them on his profile.

I cant wrap my head around the idea of cross domain validations.
For example, when the user wants to buy a badge, the system should validate that he has enough karma.
All the domains are on their on project.

This is a glimpse of the domains I have so far :

```
(Social Content Domain)
Post:
  Id
  Upvotes(down or up).
  Content
  Owner (User id)

(Users Domain)
User:
  Id
  Name
  Posts
  Karma
  Badges

(Badge Domain)
Badge:
  Id
  Name
  Category
  KarmaCost
Purchase:
  Id
  BadgeId
  UserId
  At
  Success
```

### Option 1

Using eventual consistency I will keep a copy of the user id and his karma points in the `Badge Domain`.
When the user earn/losses karma, an integration event will be sent and update the `Badge Domain` as well.
The problem for me here is that there can be a small window that the user can lose karma and in the `Badge Domain` still have sufficient karma because eventual consistency hasn't hit yet.

### Option 2

When user tries to buy a badge, the request will send a read request to the `User Domain` in order to validate how much karma he has.
Insufficient karma will result in an error.
This option makes me feel like a modeled my domains poorly.

### Option 3

Refactor the domains to the same project and access (abstractly of course) their information.

### Option 4

As a part of a transaction (of course) calling the `User Domain` with a `ConsumeKarma()` method that if consumes successfully, given the badge. 
If faulted, calling `RevertKarmaConsumption()`

Which of the above is the more DDD option ?